# Changing two fields in large table from varchar to nvarchar and back again has made table very slow, large differentials on backup also?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, t-sql

A colleague of mine changed two fields on a large table that relates to forum posts from varchar to nvarchar and then back again.  The two original fields were varchar(500) and varchar(8000) and were changed to nvarchar(500) and nvarchar(max) and back again.  The table contains approximately 1 million rows, one of the fields is for forum posts and so can contain a decent amount of text.  This table seems to have foreign keys for both the registration table and the table containing the forum topic where the replies are present.

On making the change queries to this table seem to be a lot slower, leading to timeouts.  I've noticed that there was a differential to the backup at roughly the time the field was changed to nvarchar of 1.3GB, which is much larger than a regular differential backup for this db.  Presumably this was changing the post field from varchar to nvarchar.  The odd thing is the differential is now absolutely huge each time, as if it is backing up the entire db.  This is causing the additional problem of losing space on the hd.

What has caused this problem and how can we fix it?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding or reorganizing your indexes?  ( I am assuming the table was indexed prior to the column data type change )  This should get you started in your investigation:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858.aspx

Comment: We haven't no, unfortunately this isn't my area of expertise, my knowledge of SQL extends to basic queries and updates.  I will have a look at the link and try to work it out. Thanks

Comment: The concern is not only the very slow table, but the massive increase in db size and the differentials now being the entire db instead of tiny 60mb or so changes a lot of the time.

Comment: Try taking a full backup

Comment: In general, when you backup a database, you are also backing up the corresponding indexes too.  In other words, indexes take up space too.

Comment: Thanks for your input, is there any reason why the differential backup would consistently be the entire db size every 15 minutes (which is how often a differential backup is taken)?  It seems the initial differential would be large but then there is no reason for it to continue to be so large.

Comment: Is this MySQL or MS SQL Server? You've tagged both

Comment: SQL Server, rebuilding the indexes seems to have helped significantly

Answer (score 0):

Check your recovery model, truncate logs or create backup.